# Pandas Inner Join with axis is one

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation

I was working with inner join using concat in pandas.
Using two DataFrames as below:-

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',2]], columns=['letter','number'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([['c',3,'cat'],['d',4,'dog']],
                    columns=['letter','number','animal'])

pd.concat([df1,df3], join='inner')
```

The out is below

```
letter  number
0   a   1
1   b   2
0   c   3
1   d   4
```

But after using axis=1 the output is as below

```
pd.concat([df1,df3], join='inner', axis=1)

letter  number  letter  number  animal
0   a   1   c   3   cat
1   b   2   d   4   dog
```

Why it is showing animal column while doing inner join when axis=1?

Comment: axis = 1 mean they will check the index and find the join index , not column check

Answer (score 1):

In *Pandas.concat()*

**axis** argument defines whether to concat the dataframes based on **index** or **columns**.

```
axis=0 // based on index (default value)
axis=1 // based on columns
```

when you Concatenated df1 and df3, it ***uses index to combine*** dataframes and thus output is

```
letter  number
0   a   1
1   b   2
0   c   3
1   d   4
```

But when you used axis=1, pandas combined the data ***based on columns***.
thats why the output is

```
letter  number  letter  number  animal
0   a   1   c   3   cat
1   b   2   d   4   dog
```

> EDIT:

you asked `But inner join only join same column right? Then why it is showing 'animal' column?`

So, Because right now you have 2 rows in both the dataframes and `join` only works in indexes.

For explaining to you, I have added another row in df3
Let's suppose df3 is

```
   0  1     2
0  c  3   cat
1  d  4   dog
2  e  5  bird
```

Now, If you concat the df1 and df3

`pd.concat([df1,df3], join='inner', axis=1)`

```
  letter  number  0  1    2
0      a       1  c  3  cat
1      b       2  d  4  dog
```

`pd.concat([df1,df3], join='outer', axis=1)`

```
  letter  number  0  1     2
0      a     1.0  c  3   cat
1      b     2.0  d  4   dog
2    NaN     NaN  e  5  bird
```

As you can see, in inner join only `0 and 1` indexes are in output
but in outer join, all the indexes are in output with `NAN` values.

Comment: But inner join only join same column right? Then why it is showing 'animal' column?

Comment: answered your query in post.

Comment: Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the axis is 0. So in the first concat call axis=0 and over there concatenation happens in rows. When you set axis=1 the operation is similar to

```
df1.merge( df3, how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```